# Kuberentes nginx subdomain

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Host2 (subdomain) works perfect, host 1 gives error message '**default backend - 404**'. Both dockerfiles for web1 and web2 works on local machine and YAML files is almost identical except for name variables, nodePort and image location etc..

Any ideas what can be wrong here?

**Ingress config:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: test-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host1.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: web1
              servicePort: 80
    - host: sub.host1.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: web2
              servicePort: 80
```

**YAML for web1**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web1
spec:
  selector:
    app: web1
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      nodePort: 32112
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web1-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web1
  replicas: 1
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web1
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - name: web1
          image: gcr.io/image..
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          # HTTP Health Check
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Can you share how you are sending the requests that work on host2 and the requests that fail on host1? Thanks!

Comment: Using curl http://host1 and http://host2?

Comment: So you are not using a subdomain like you mention in your question? Vaguely describing your problem makes it harder to provide help.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host1.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: web1
              servicePort: 80
    - host: sub.host1.com
      http:
       paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: web2
              servicePort: 80
```

---

I think this should work. I am also using same config. Please correct indentation issues if any in the yaml, I posted here